# CSV modify duplicate & algorithm "paradox", in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm a beginner with python (2.7).
So here is my file :

```
data, 1234, data
data, 6868, data
data, 3545, data
data, 6868, data
data, 7777, data
data, 3545, data
```

I want to check duplicate (only in column 2) and increment +1 one of the duplicate, like that :

```
data, 1234, data
data, 6868, data
data, 3545, data
data, 6869, data
data, 7777, data
data, 3546, data
```

I did something like this but it's write only lines where duplicates are :

```
entries = set()
for row in reader:
    key = row[2] 
    if key in entries:
        aaa = row[2]
        bbb = int(aaa) + 1 
        ccc = str(bbb)
        entries.add(ccc)
    else:
        entries.add(key)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

I dont see how do this.

But I asking myself about an other question : if the incremented number is now a duplicate, how I can check that ? It will not create an infinite loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you iterate through your file, store values of column 2 in a `set`, and when you encounter a repeat value, increment by 1 using `while` until the value becomes unique. Store the new value, and write the entire line to file using a `csv.writer`:

```
import csv

data = set()
with open ('task1.txt', 'rb') as file_in, open ('output.txt', 'wb') as fileout:
    reader = csv.reader(file_in)
    writer = csv.writer(fileout)
    for line in reader:
        idx = int(line[1])
        while idx in data:
            idx += 1
        data.add(idx)
        line[1] = str(idx)

        writer.writerow(line)
```

Note: in Python2.7, we open the filehandles `buffer` mode (i.e. `rb` instead of `r`, but this is unnecessary in Python3.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I got error "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level" in " idx += 1"

Comment: @csvunleasher python is strict how to indent you code. use consistent indent space when you create blocks. for starter indent using a tab consistently and try again

Comment: Damn, what a shame, I though this was a incrementation error. But, I got this error : "TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function "

Comment: use `wb` mode instead of `w` and get rid of the `newline` parameter

Comment: Hey again @waterboy5281. I got a new problem because now I want to modify the next duplicate (no the first). How I can do that ?

Comment: Happy to help, but I don't understand. can you provide sample input/output in your original post?

Comment: Thanks for replying @waterboy5281. I edited my post. Maybe its possible by read the file from the end to the beginning ?

Comment: Well, you're right ! My file is big, didn't see the lines. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It won't create an infinite loop, unless you have infinite data. :) Your code is close - you can handle the incremented number colliding with an existing number by using [`while` with an `else` clause](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) instead of `if ... else`. You also need to update the `row` with the new key.

Here's a version that reads the data from a string, to make it easier to test.

```
import csv

table = '''\
data, 6870, data
data, 6869, data
data, 1234, data
data, 6868, data
data, 3545, data
data, 6868, data
data, 7777, data
data, 3545, data
'''

reader = csv.reader(table.splitlines(), skipinitialspace=True)
entries = set()
for row in reader:
    print(' IN', row)
    while row[1] in entries:
        row[1] = str(int(row[1]) + 1) 
    else:
        entries.add(row[1])
    print('OUT', row, end='\n\n')
```

**output**

```
 IN ['data', '6870', 'data']
OUT ['data', '6870', 'data']

 IN ['data', '6869', 'data']
OUT ['data', '6869', 'data']

 IN ['data', '1234', 'data']
OUT ['data', '1234', 'data']

 IN ['data', '6868', 'data']
OUT ['data', '6868', 'data']

 IN ['data', '3545', 'data']
OUT ['data', '3545', 'data']

 IN ['data', '6868', 'data']
OUT ['data', '6871', 'data']

 IN ['data', '7777', 'data']
OUT ['data', '7777', 'data']

 IN ['data', '3545', 'data']
OUT ['data', '3546', 'data']
```

To run this code on Python 2 add this at the start of the script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @PM 2Ring, this is the solution. I tried this : 

`with open ('result4.csv', 'r') as file_in, open ('result5.csv', 'w') as fileout:
     reader = csv.reader(file_in.splitlines(), skipinitialspace=True)
     entries = set()
     for row in reader:
      while row[4] in entries:
       row[4] = str(int(row[4]) + 1) 
      else:
       entries.add(row[4])

      writer.writerow(row)`


but file as not attribute splitlines

Comment: @csvunleasher It's really hard to read multi-line code in comments. In future, you should add it to the bottom of your question, maybe after a `<hr>` tag. You shouldn't use `.splitline()` I just used that to convert my `table` string into a list; the CSV Reader can accept a list or a file (or a file-like object). You should just do `reader = csv.reader(file_in, skipinitialspace=True)`. But you need to open both the files in binary mode, `open('result4.csv', 'rb')` and `open('result5.csv', 'wb')`

Comment: @csvunleasher FWIW, the `skipinitialspace=True` tells the Reader to ignore any spaces immediately after the comma field separator.

Comment: Thanks ! @PM 2Ring I modified it for my code and its worked